# Why do I get a popup instead of an in-page modal dialog box when call requireSession or click on fb:login-button?

Tags: facebook

Update: The problem seems to have magically fixed itself, because I don't know what changed. If someone has an idea about how I accidentally fixed it, please post (I include myself :P).

I'm trying to use Facebook Connect on my site, but I'm having trouble with using requireSession or fb:login-button. Currently, when a user clicks the connect button, they get a popup window,but I really want to show an in-page modal. How do I do that? Currently, what I've got in pages is this HTML code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="FB.Connect.requireSession(on_session_ready); return false;">
  Connect with Facebook&nbsp;
  <img id="fb_login_image"
       src="http://b.static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/fbconnect/login-buttons/connect_dark_small_short.gif"
       alt="Connect"/>
</a>
```

(I'm pretty sure it `on_session_ready` doesn't matter for problem, because it only gets called *after* fb connect gets a session.)

I've also tried using the fb:login-button XFBML tag, but I also get a popup window when I do that.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You** are not doing anything wrong. **Facebook** is currently split-testing modal vs popup login boxes.

They will most likely settle on popups for security reasons. But in the meantime, you have no control over which type of dialog box your users see.

PS: This is well-covered on the Facebook Developer Forums.

- http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=25808
- http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=157799
- http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=29523

Comment: Thanks Portman. I've found the FB forums to be pretty useless, at least for answering questions, so I didn't notice those posts. Thanks for including them.

Comment: I just scanned over the threads that you linked to, and I don't see any official word on split testing (but maybe I missed it). Has fb made an official announcement?

PS: If I'm right, those threads confirmed what I said in my previous comment about how useless the forums are <irony/>.

Comment: Ha! You're right, no official word on the forum. But rest assured, that is what is going on. (Full disclosure: my company runs a Facebook ad network.)